# Submitting Formdata using XHR

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

apologies if this is already answered somewhere else but it seems I'm having a very specific problem regarding uploading files using the `FormData` Object.

The HTML form:

```
<form id="file-form" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple onchange="HandleFileInput(event); return false;"/>
</form>
```

The JS callback:

```
HandleFileInput(event) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var fileList = document.getElementById('file-input').files;
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        fd.append(fileList[i].name, fileList[i]);
    }
}
```

Using the debugger I can see the fileList is indeed filled with file entries (multiple), and I can access the individual files by indexing them in the console. However, it seems that I cannot append the files to the FormData object. After the for-loop the fd object is still empty. Help?

Comment: "After the for-loop the fd object is still empty" — This is almost certainly an artefact of how you are trying to view the contents. Just submit the data. It should be fine.

Comment: What makes you think that the files are not appended to the `FormData` object?

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything is indeed appended to the object as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems everything is appended to the fd object as intended. I checked this using the `values()` function of the fd object:

```
for (var value of fd.values()) {
    console.log(value)
}
```